# Cron doesn't accept bash syntax

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bashscript that I'm running with crontab.  Unfortunately, a script that works fine when run manually fails with the error:

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")`

Where the line in question is line 22 which is:

`declare -a PREV_TOTAL=( $(for i in ${range[@]}; do echo 0; done) )`

In the larger context:

```
TOTAL_CPU_USAGE=0
    TOTAL_CPU=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) #set number of CPUs to check for
    declare -a 'range=({'"0..$TOTAL_CPU"'})'
    let "TOTAL_CPU=$TOTAL_CPU - 1"

    #declare array of size TOTAL_CPU to store values (eg. 8 cpus makes arrays of size 8)
    declare -a PREV_TOTAL=( $(for i in ${range[@]}; do echo 0; done) )
    declare -a PREV_IDLE=( $(for i in ${range[@]}; do echo 0; done) )
```

This works when manually just fine, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong that causes cron to give this error?  If you know I'd be very appreciative.  Thanks.

EDIT: My crontab looks like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot cd /home/ubuntu/waste-cloud-computing/probe && probe.sh >> /var/log/somelogfile.log 2>&1
```

And I access it with `sudo crontab -e`.  I'm still getting the issue while providing the SHELL variable.

EDIT 1: Thanks to some help I got past the syntax issues by ensuring the shell was using bash.  Now I get the error, `/bin/bash: probe.bash: command not found`.  I assume its some kind of PATH issue, but `which bash` returns `/bin/bash` so it seems normal to me.  Maybe someone knows what's up?

Comment: Is `cron` actually executing your script with `bash`, or with `sh`?

Comment: cron is run by sh by default, not bash

Comment: You need to use the full pathname for `/some/directory/probe.sh` (or `./probe.sh` if that cd goes there) in the crontab, since whatever you set PATH to in your shell startup, cron is unaware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the people here I found my issue was not syntax but rather the use of sh over bash.  This was fixed by setting the crontab this way so future users can see:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot cd /home/ubuntu/waste-cloud-computing/probe && ./probe.sh >> /var/log/somelogfile.log 2>&1
```

The key points are the SHELL variable being set and the ./ before running the script.

Answer (score 3):

cron jobs are run by sh by default, not bash. If you are using ubuntu/vixiecron, you can set the SHELL env variable at the top of the crontab to make cron run the commands in your crontab with bash.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

If the script you want to be run is a bash script, make sure you have a shebang at the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Also note that there will be other potential troubleshooting steps if your scripts depend on a particular user's profile, env vars, etc. depending on which crontab you are editing.

Comment: Is this something that would be system specific? Mine quite explicitly states: *"The command portion of a cron job is run with /bin/sh -c ..."* And also *"Unlike  other cron daemons, this crond/crontab package doesn't try to do everything under the sun.  It doesn't try to keep track of user's preferred shells; ...Instead, it just runs all commands using /bin/sh.  (Commands can of course be script files written in any shell you like.)"* I.e. I might be changing a variable, but not a shell that is being executed.

Comment: I guess it would depend on the specific cron implementation. In vixiecron setting SHELL will tell cron which shell to use to execute the command.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that probably is the problem.  I don't think I should have a lot of problems with env and stuff, but I won't know until I get it working.  I did what you said and still get the same error.  I provided the crontab in the edit.

Comment: @SoZettaSho thanks for your continued assistance.  It is in fact a .sh, but I didn't think it mattered because my shebang is `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file.  I tried it with both .sh and .bash file extensions anyways and I now get `/bin/bash: probe.sh: command not found` or the same with .bash.  Is there something I'm missing in my crontab?  Should it be something like `... sh probe.sh ...`   ?

Comment: You could try `bash ./probe.sh` to see if it works, but note that will spin up an expensive and unnecessary subshell. You will need to use `./probe.sh` instead of `probe.sh` since it's not in your path.

Comment: @AshtonSpina File extensions don't matter, except that the file name (including extension) *must* match the name used in the crontab entry. Do *not* use `... sh probe.sh ...`, because that'll run it in `sh` rather than `bash`, and also look for the script file in whatever chron uses as the default directory (probably the account's home directory) rather than in `$PATH`. Speaking of which, where is this script located?